# Using a different font inside an environment

Tags: fonts, environments

I would like to define an “Example” environment, numbered within chapters, and that this environment also used a different font than the rest of the text. I know how to create the environment, but I can't figure out how to make the environment use the Libertinus font.

My definition, so far, looks like this:

```
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin{example}{chapter}
\newenvironment{argument}[1][\unskip]{%
\par
\noindent
\def\temp{#1}\ifx\temp\empty
\textbf{Example~\theexample:}
\else
\textbf{Example~\theexample (#1):}
\fi
\noindent}
{\vspace*{2em}}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/5764)

Comment: Follow the link provided by Werner. Have a look at the part where a font is selected using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Presumably if you are using Libertinus you are using LuaTeX or XeTeX, so everything in the best answer there should work for you.